# has admin access but throws System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied.'

Tags: c#

Ok so it opens as administrator, I've put requireAdministrator in the app.manifest, it has access because it writes the file but it does the System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied.' when it tries to run it. so is it the folder its going to or is it something else?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace testing_code
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("type off");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if(userInput == "off")
            {
            turnOffUAC();
            };
        Console.WriteLine("well did it work?");
        Console.ReadLine();
        static void turnOffUAC()
        {
       
                //this is the path the document or in our case batch file will be placed
                
                string path1 = "c:\\LegendTools";

                // this is the batch commands remember its "", the comma seperates the lines
                string[] lines =
                {
                "@echo off",
                "reg.exe ADD HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",
                "del \"%~f0\""
                };
            //this writes the string to the file
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path1, "test.bat")))
            {
                //This writes the file line by line
                foreach (string line in lines)
                    outputFile.WriteLine(line);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path1);
```

Comment: At which line? Incidentally, you can do registry edits direct from C#

Comment: `Process.Start(path1);` Do you really mean to `Start` the *directory* there?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path1); is where it throws

Comment: Dxiv you figured it out

Comment: i just read that i could do reg edits with c# but this only helps me in this one, gotta run a bunch of commands through command prompt so batch files it is for me

Answer (score 0):

thanks to thanks to [Dxiv's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv) wise words its been fixed
It throws the error at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path1);
this is because string path1 = "c:\LegendTools"; is trying to start the directory not the bat file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace testing_code
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("type off");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if(userInput == "off")
        {
        turnOffUAC();
        };
    Console.WriteLine("well did it work?");
    Console.ReadLine();
    static void turnOffUAC()
    {
   
            //this is the path the document or in our case batch file will be placed
            
            string docPath = "c:\\LegendTools";
            string path1 = docPath + "\\Test.bat";

            // this is the batch commands remember its "", the comma seperates the lines
            string[] lines =
            {
            "@echo off",
            "reg.exe ADD HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",
            "del \"%~f0\""
            };
        //this writes the string to the file
         using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, "test.bat")))
        {
            //This writes the file line by line
            foreach (string line in lines)
                outputFile.WriteLine(line);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path1);
```